# How to remove day from DateTimePicker value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, datetimepicker

I need my DateTimePicker to return a value in the format of "M/yyyy". I have set it to a custom format of "M/yyyy" and set it to use an updown control instead of a calendar, so the user isn't forced to choose a day. I have also tried removing the day entirely from the "value" section in properties, but it still returns a value in the format of "M/D/yyyy".

[Here is an example of the issue, I just have a message box showing the value in the "Due" DateTimePicker.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49TNi.png)

Comment: The DateTimePicker will only return a valid datetime. I think you will just have to accept the default 1st day of the month and format it as needed when you display it anywhere. `dtp1.Value.ToString("M/yyyy")`. You might be able to get the effect you want with a MaskedTextBox and some code that insures limits on the month number. (ie, so you can't type 13 as a month)

Comment: adding .ToString("M/yyyy") worked perfect! Thanks